# Regex possible Whitespaces and trailing characters

Tags: regex

I have texts similar to the following (whitespaces intended), which i run a RegEx on line-by-line:

```
 Smith-Petersen                 X1l
Jonas Henry           
Foord. 82a                     221.
 12345 Somewhere
```

I now want to use the RegEx to capture anything before 3 or more whitespaces occur (which might or might not occur) in the first match group. The allowed chars:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9,. '\-AÖÜäöüß]
```

What I want is : `Smith-Petersen`, `Jonas Henry`, `Foord. 82a` and `12345 Somewhere`. 
After trying desperately, I hope to find help with this here...I just can't get it to work since my expression grabs the blanks and what follows and puts it into the first group as well. Is there a ways to reverse the way the RegEx? Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming by "may or may not occur" you mean the line may end before 3 spaces are encountered:

```
^\s*([-a-zA-Z0-9,\.'AÖÜäöüß ]+?)(?=\s{3}|\s{0,2}$)
```

This regex is using a positive look ahead to assert that either there's 3 spaces following or there's up to 2 spaces then end-of-input.

The anchor to start of input avoids matching the junk at the end of the longer lines.

Your target is in group 1.

See a [live demo on rubular](http://rubular.com/r/0dsjHlYatY)

Comment: Much better than mine now :)

Comment: I tested this in .Net and it seems the range {,2} doesn't work there. I had to change it to {0,2} for it to work. OP might need to keep that in mind depending on what regex engine he uses.

Comment: Yup, .Net as well, thanks for the info! I will try this when I'm back in the office

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach.

```
^ *([a-zA-Z0-9,.'AÖÜäöüß-]+(?: {1,2}[a-zA-Z0-9,.'AÖÜäöüß-]+)*)
```

What you want is in match group 1. This regex uses only greedy operators and works on all four cases found in your sample text.

Basically it matches all words at the beginning of a line that are separated from one another by no more than two spaces. Once more than 2 spaces are found, the match is completed.